# Roof a DateTime to next value of a specific minute interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to display information in sections with a specific interval, for example 5, 10, 15, etc. minutes.

But I want to kind of "round up" to the next value of this interval for a given DateTime

e.g.

```
declare @dateTime datetime = '2014-03-05 18:37';

select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 60); --> 2014-03-05 19:00
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 30); --> 2014-03-05 19:00
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 20); --> 2014-03-05 18:40
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 15); --> 2014-03-05 18:45
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 10); --> 2014-03-05 18:40
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 5);  --> 2014-03-05 18:40
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 1);  --> 2014-03-05 18:38
```

Is there a clever way to do this? I only have come up with solutions that will only work for some of these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work:

```
create function dbo.getNextDateTimeForInterval (@dt datetime, @unit int)
returns datetime
as
begin
    return DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,0,@dt)/@unit+1)*@unit,0)
end
go
declare @dateTime datetime = '2014-03-05T18:37:00';

select dbo.getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 60); --> 2014-03-05 19:00
select dbo.getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 30); --> 2014-03-05 19:00
select dbo.getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 20); --> 2014-03-05 18:40
select dbo.getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 15); --> 2014-03-05 18:45
select dbo.getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 10); --> 2014-03-05 18:40
select dbo.getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 5);  --> 2014-03-05 18:40
select dbo.getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 1);  --> 2014-03-05 18:38
```

Nothing especially tricksy needed. Although if you use intervals that don't divide 60 evenly, I won't guarantee that it'll match your expectations, because I have no idea what your expectations might be for such a situation.

---

Explanation: `DATEDIFF(minute,0,@dt)` computes the whole number of minutes that have elapsed between midnight at the start of `1900-01-01` (the value you obtain by interpreting `0` as a date) and `@dt`. We then do an integer divide (which rounds towards 0) that value by `@unit`, add 1 and then multiply it back up by `@unit` - which is how we're getting our rounding up effect. And then we use `DATEADD` to add that new number of minutes back onto `1900-01-01`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their answers, but yours was the most detailed one so I will give you the credit.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that returns the correct values for your test cases:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNextDateTimeForInterval(@param datetime, @roundValue int)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @totalMinutes int;
    SET @totalMinutes = DATEDIFF(
            minute
            , CONVERT(date, @param)
            , @param);

    RETURN DATEADD(minute
        , @totalMinutes + (@roundValue - (@totalMinutes % @roundValue))
        , CONVERT(DateTime, CONVERT(date, @param))
    );
END
```

But note that if you want `18:37, 1 -->18:38`, then it'll also be `19:00, 60 -->20:00`. That may be odd.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime datetime, @val int)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = CONVERT(varchar(16),@dateTime,121) 
RETURN DATEADD(MINUTE,((DATEPART(MINUTE,@date) % @val)*-1)+@val, @date)

END


select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 60); --> 2014-03-05 19:00
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 30); --> 2014-03-05 19:00
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 20); --> 2014-03-05 18:40
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 15); --> 2014-03-05 18:45
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 10); --> 2014-03-05 18:40
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 5);  --> 2014-03-05 18:40
select getNextDateTimeForInterval(@dateTime, 1);  --> 2014-03-05 18:38
```